# circularly linked list showing strange behavior with pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, queue, circular-list

I have a small thread pool example for learn use:

It takes work structs which represent a simple calculation (+, -, *, /) of two values.
Now the worker threads will pull these work structs out of the queue and execute them.

So much to the theory. The problem now is that when I want to use the helper function submit_work() somehow the queue resolving in the worker thread does not work (the data pulled out is invalid and when I use QUEUE_REMOVE it does an segmentation fault).

**How can it be that by just using an helper function the whole concept does not work anymore?**

**pool.c**

I mean pushing data manually works fine...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "../queue/queue.h"

#define MAX_THREADS 1

pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];

pthread_cond_t cond;   

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

/**
 * QUEUE is a "void * arr[2]".
 * The Queue itself is similar to the circularly linked list in linux
 */
QUEUE queue;

struct work_s {
    int a;
    int b;
    int type;
    QUEUE node;
};

void * worker();
void submit_work(int a, int b, int type);

int main() {
    QUEUE_INIT(&queue);

    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    struct work_s work[2];

    /* 5 + 7 */
    work[0].a = 5;
    work[0].b = 7;
    work[0].type = 1;

    /* 3 x 3 */
    work[1].a = 3;
    work[1].b = 3;
    work[1].type = 3;

    /* initialize there queue nodes */
    QUEUE_INIT(&work[0].node);
    QUEUE_INIT(&work[1].node);

    /* insert both tasks into the work queue */
    QUEUE_INSERT_TAIL(&queue, &work[0].node);
    QUEUE_INSERT_TAIL(&queue, &work[1].node);

    /* this does actually the same as above but causes a segmentation fault. */
    submit_work(5, 6, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_detach(threads[i]);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

    return 0;
}

void submit_work(int a, int b, int type) {
    struct work_s work;

    work.a = a;
    work.b = b;
    work.type = type;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    QUEUE_INIT(&work.node);
    QUEUE_INSERT_TAIL(&queue, &work.node);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
}

void * worker() { 
    /* a pointer to a queue node */
    QUEUE * q;

    int result;

    struct work_s * work;

    /* infinite loop */
    for (;;) {
        while (QUEUE_EMPTY(&queue)) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        q = QUEUE_HEAD(&queue);

        /* HERE THE SEGMENTSTION FAULT OCCURS when using submit_work */
        QUEUE_REMOVE(q);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        /* set the work pointer to the work struct we have pulled from queue */
        work = QUEUE_DATA(q, struct work_s, node);

        /* PRINTS INCORRECT DATA on submit_work() */
        printf("received work type %d with a %d and b %d \n", work->a, work->b, work->type);

        if (work->type == 0) {
            break;
        }

        switch (work->type) {
            case 1:
                result = work->a + work->b;
                printf("%d + %d = %d\n", work->a, work->b, result);
                break;
            case 2:
                result = work->a - work->b;
                printf("%d - %d = %d\n", work->a, work->b, result);
                break;
            case 3:
                result = work->a * work->b;
                printf("%d * %d = %d\n", work->a, work->b, result);
                break;
            case 4:
                result = work->a / work->b;
                printf("%d / %d = %d\n", work->a, work->b, result);
                break;
        }
    }


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

**queue.h**

```
/* Copyright (c) 2013, Ben Noordhuis <info@bnoordhuis.nl>
 *
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
 * purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
 * copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
 * WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
 * ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
 * WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
 * ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
 * OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
 */

#ifndef QUEUE_H_
#define QUEUE_H_

typedef void *QUEUE[2];

/* Private macros. */
#define QUEUE_NEXT(q)       ((*(q))[0])
#define QUEUE_PREV(q)       ((*(q))[1])
#define QUEUE_PREV_NEXT(q)  (QUEUE_NEXT((QUEUE *) QUEUE_PREV(q)))
#define QUEUE_NEXT_PREV(q)  (QUEUE_PREV((QUEUE *) QUEUE_NEXT(q)))

/* Public macros. */
#define QUEUE_DATA(ptr, type, field)                                          \
  ((type *) ((char *) (ptr) - ((long) &((type *) 0)->field)))

#define QUEUE_FOREACH(q, h)                                                   \
  for ((q) = (*(h))[0]; (q) != (h); (q) = (*(q))[0])

#define QUEUE_EMPTY(q)                                                        \
  (QUEUE_NEXT(q) == (q))

#define QUEUE_HEAD(q)                                                         \
  (QUEUE_NEXT(q))

#define QUEUE_INIT(q)                                                         \
  do {                                                                        \
    QUEUE_NEXT(q) = (q);                                                      \
    QUEUE_PREV(q) = (q);                                                      \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)

#define QUEUE_ADD(h, n)                                                       \
  do {                                                                        \
    QUEUE_PREV_NEXT(h) = QUEUE_NEXT(n);                                       \
    QUEUE_NEXT_PREV(n) = QUEUE_PREV(h);                                       \
    QUEUE_PREV(h) = QUEUE_PREV(n);                                            \
    QUEUE_PREV_NEXT(h) = (h);                                                 \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)

#define QUEUE_SPLIT(h, q, n)                                                  \
  do {                                                                        \
    QUEUE_PREV(n) = QUEUE_PREV(h);                                            \
    QUEUE_PREV_NEXT(n) = (n);                                                 \
    QUEUE_NEXT(n) = (q);                                                      \
    QUEUE_PREV(h) = QUEUE_PREV(q);                                            \
    QUEUE_PREV_NEXT(h) = (h);                                                 \
    QUEUE_PREV(q) = (n);                                                      \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)

#define QUEUE_INSERT_HEAD(h, q)                                               \
  do {                                                                        \
    QUEUE_NEXT(q) = QUEUE_NEXT(h);                                            \
    QUEUE_PREV(q) = (h);                                                      \
    QUEUE_NEXT_PREV(q) = (q);                                                 \
    QUEUE_NEXT(h) = (q);                                                      \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)

#define QUEUE_INSERT_TAIL(h, q)                                               \
  do {                                                                        \
    QUEUE_NEXT(q) = (h);                                                      \
    QUEUE_PREV(q) = QUEUE_PREV(h);                                            \
    QUEUE_PREV_NEXT(q) = (q);                                                 \
    QUEUE_PREV(h) = (q);                                                      \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)

#define QUEUE_REMOVE(q)                                                       \
  do {                                                                        \
    QUEUE_PREV_NEXT(q) = QUEUE_NEXT(q);                                       \
    QUEUE_NEXT_PREV(q) = QUEUE_PREV(q);                                       \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)

#endif /* QUEUE_H_ */
```

If I should also copy the QUEUE.h file leave a comment. Else you find it [here](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/src/queue.h)

Bodo

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you shouldn't have a loop that calls `pthread_detach(threads[i]);` after you've joined those threads.  Join and detach are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I though pthread_join would block until threads are finished? Where to you recommend to place it?

Comment: `pthread_join()` does block until the thread is finished; however once you have joined a thread you can't call `pthread_detach()` on it (and there's no reason to). So my recommendation is to just get rid of the detach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are inserting a local variable of `submit_work()` onto the queue (the queue routines do not make a copy of the object they are queueing). So once `submit_work()` returns, the data in the structure that was queued is  no longer valid (and likely changes the link pointers to garbage).

This doesn't occur for the first two items enqueued because their lifetime is still valid while the thread functions execute since `main()` blocks in the `pthread_join()` calls.

You should be queueing items that are dynamically allocated so their lifetime extends past the lfe of the function that queues them.  Of course, then you also need to have the functions that dequeue the items free the memory. Of course this means that you should also dynamically allocate the items enqueued directly by `main()`.

Comment: Great thanks for this answer!! I would have never find that this would be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You execute this loop in `worker()` without holding the mutex:

```
while (QUEUE_EMPTY(&queue)) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
}
```

`pthread_cond_wait()` can only be called while holding the mutex you pass to it - it'll also return with that mutex locked, so you shouldn't immediately call `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)` after that loop - it's already locked.

So that bit of code should look something like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (QUEUE_EMPTY(&queue)) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
}

// don't call pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) here...
```

Comment: I changed that but the problem still remains. I try to load this somewhere up where you can run it yourself. wait

Comment: Do a cd to threads and then you can run make pool && ./pool.o https://c9.io/bodokaiser/libuv-internals

Comment: Maybe you can post `queue.h` into the question - I can't really do anything more than read it on cloud9. I wonder if your problem is thread related or just a plain old bug in the queue handling.  Maybe you can take all the thread-related code out of your program and have `main()` just call `worker()` after `submit_work()` and see if you get a similar crash.

Comment: as the queue is used havily in production I guess its thread related